# Composition vs. Inheritance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

i try to understand the difference between Composition and Inheritance in swift but i can't find a simple and easy answer that can help me to understand the difference between them and how i can choose which one to use

Comment: https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose

Comment: Composition is `"has a"` or `"contains a"` relationship.. whereas inheritance is `"is a"` or `"is a type of"` relationship..  Example: A Gorilla has 2 Legs (composition - Gorilla class would have 2 instance of Leg class).. However.. A Gorilla is an Animal (inheritance).. Thus Gorilla would inherit all the properties and traits of an animal. This is not specific to swift. It's for all Object-Oriented languages.

Comment: Please see the duplicate question. It may not seem as a duplicate at first. But its answes surely provide enough to ponder

Comment: Honey thank you i found my answer there

Comment: @HazemMohamed Brandon's comment is also very valuable The **Has-a** and **Is-a** are very easy to understand rules. For more see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Has-a)